# Apache CXF OAuthDataProvider in a JAX-RS web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oauth, cxf, jax-rs

I'm writing a plain JAX-RS web application that exposes a REST API; I use Spring, but only for actual configuration, and rely on plain CXF and Hibernate for all other functionality.

I now want to secure certain parts of the API with OAuth 1.0. To do this, I am trying to use [`org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.provider.OAuthDataProvider`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/rs/security/oauth/provider/OAuthDataProvider.html) (Along with some other beans) in conjunction with my database.

However, I find the documentation to be very unclear, and it's difficult to find examples showing how this bean is supposed to be used. Specifically, these things are unclear:

- The `createAccessToken` and `createRequestToken` methods are supposed to create tokens. I do presumably also have to persist the generated tokens to the database. But how much of each token do I have to persist? Is it enough to store `(consumerKey, tokenId, tokenSecret)` or is it necessary to also persist e.g. the client secret, the callback URI, scopes, etc?
- Similarly, in `getAccessToken` and `getRequestToken`, how much do I have to "fill in" for the service to work? Is it enough to provide the token ID and secret, or do I really have to provide a whole `Client` object as well, etc?
- What exactly do I have to provide in `finalizeAuthorization`?
- If I skip doing any of the above (e.g. by not setting the client secret in `getAccessToken`), do I lose some functionality?

I have a fairly solid understanding of the OAuth 1.0 protocol; the reason for most of the questions above is that it's difficult to discern what CXF keeps track of for me.

Answer (score 3):

I agree documentation is really poor about details in section [Writing OAuthDataProvider of OAuth 1.0 JAX-RS documentation for CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth.html#JAX-RSOAuth-WritingOAuthDataProvider). I would say CXF does not keep track of anything, as this interface is supposed to provide token creation and persistence.

You are completely free how to do token creation and persistence, either with in memory storage or database persistence with direct JDBC or Hibernate.

I propose you get inspiration from the following examples:

- [Sample implementation (in memory)](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/oauth/server/src/main/java/demo/oauth/server/controllers/MemoryOAuthDataProvider.java) from CXF and maybe also its [initial commit](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-commits/201007.mbox/%3C20100714213420.3EC6123889E0@eris.apache.org%3E) in sandbox.
- [globus-oauth-demo](https://code.google.com/p/globus-oauth-demo/source/browse/trunk/restapp/webapp/WEB-INF/oauth-beans.xml?r=100) project

... and guess the remaining details in debug session.

Hope this helps

Comment: The in-memory sample implementation does not help because the HashMap that is used stores every field of a Token, so I don't know which fields are needed or not. The Globus demo might provide the details I need, I will have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

CXF OAuthDataProvider is expected to be a data centric implementation having little to do with OAuth2 related issues, though it can add its own validation on top of what the runtime and grant handlers do...